# Dynamic Menu in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a `dynamic menu` by using `AngularJS`. Everything working proper by using below code; Now I am keeping `ParentID` is `0`. If I change `ParentID`to `NULL` then below code is not generating menu properly.

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);

myApp.controller("MyAppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
console.log("From controller");

$scope.SiteMenu = [];
$http.get('/Home/GetDynamicMenu').then(function (response) {
    $scope.SiteMenu = response.data;
    console.log($scope.SiteMenu);
}, function (error) {
    alert('Error');
})
```

});

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
    {{45+50}}
    <br />
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeMenu">
        <a href="{{menu.MenuUrl}}">{{menu.MenuName}}</a>
        @* We will create submenu only when available *@
        @*<ul ng-if="(SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}).length > 0">*@
        <ul ng-if="(SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}).length > 0">
            @*<li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>*@
            <li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID} : true" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <ul class="main-navigation">
        @* Here we will load only top level menu *@
        @*<li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : 0}" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>*@
        <li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : NULL} : true" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think the issue in below Angular filter in HTML line. Can any one change this filter to NULL.

```
<ul ng-if="(SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}).length > 0">
```

Comment: Can you explain in your question why you'd use `null` and what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Our table structure is like that.. If it is a first menu item then its ParentID is NULL. Its a dynamic menu by using ParentID and MainID relation

Comment: ... *in your question*.